# C# WPF: FrameworkElementFactory add ComboBox Event Handler for DropDownClosed

Tags: c#, event-handling, wpf-controls, .net-7.0, frameworkelementfactory

I'm struggling to add the event "DropDownClosed" to my ComboBox template similar to how you can do for other events like:

```cs
ComboBox_Template.AddHandler(GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ComboBox_GotFocus));
```

I tried to add it by simply writing

```cs
Cmb_Template.AddHandler(ComboBox.DropDownClosed, new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(cmb_OtdCategory_DropDownClosed));
```

but `ComboBox.DropDownClosed` just doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you cannot because that is not a routed event - it is just a normal clr event.